# How to create a ticker mode slider with Swiper Js

Tags: swiper.js

I want to create a ticker newspaper mode slider with swiper js. I have used the following codes, they are not working perfectly.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 1000,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    cssEase:'linear',
});
```

please suggest what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you in your case

```
let SwiperTicker = new Swiper('.swiper--top', {
  spaceBetween: 0,
  centeredSlides: true,
  speed: 6000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1,
  },
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView:'auto',
  allowTouchMove: false,
  disableOnInteraction: true
});
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Swiper doesn't have parameter `cssEase`.

I can work fine to add css.

```
.swiper-wrapper{transition-timing-function:linear; }
```

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/496

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an animation like a news ticker on TV, follow the steps below: Put this code in the JS file

```
var swiper= new Swiper(".swiper", {
    slidesPerView: 5,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    speed: 5000,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 0.1,
    },
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView:'auto',
    disableOnInteraction: true,
});
```

And in your CSS file

```
.swiper-wrapper{transition-timing-function:linear !important;}
```